# Orbeon filter problem - separate deployment

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I followed the instructions on http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications (copied the JAR, configured my web.xml, setup cross context mode in tomcat). Than I created a jsp file with xforms elements, put it in the xforms-jsp directory in my war.
When I open the .jsp in a browser, the filter doesn't seem to work, no xforms data (eg. input field) is displayed.

I just began developing web apps, so maybe i made a very trivial mistake...

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing exactly what you did. Would you be able to create a minimal web app that shows the issue, upload it somewhere, and include a link to that file in your question?

Comment: i'm not sure, i can do that. just tell me please, where am I wrong: if I open a jsp file, like: localhost:8080/servlet_proj/guess-the-number.jsp, which uses xforms tags from the xforms namespace, like <xforms:trigger>, the orbeon filter should kick in, and transform the xforms tags into xhtml, and after that, my browser should display the transformed page, with the jsp functions. In my browser, it is displayed as a plain text, even the xhtml tags are ignored, i think...

Comment: The definitely should definitely kick in if properly configured. You say you put your JSP in xforms-jsp directory. But in the comment above, your path does not include xforms-jsp. See our online examples that work: http://www.orbeon.com/orbeon/xforms-jsp/guess-the-number/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. On the next morning it worked perfectly, i think it needed a full restart...

Comment: Anvar, can I ask you if you could post an answer to your own question mentioning that a restart solved the issue? This is just so other people finding this through a search can see what the solution to the problem was for you, without having to go through all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the configuration and orbeon setup was all right, after a full restart it worked perfectly.
Thanks for the answers!